# Summation of Two random variable

Tags: random-variable, sum

Suppose $X$ is random variable with PDF $f(X)=2(x-1)$, $1 \le x \le 2$; $Y$ is a random variable with a triangle pdf with minimum at $2$, mode at $2.5$, and maximum at $3$.

Is it possible to define a random variable like $Z$ which is the summation of $X$ and $Y$? ($Z=X+Y$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent)

In this situation, what is the PDF of variable $Z$?

Comment: Is it homework? What do you mean by "medium"? Is mode ($c$ parameter for triangular distribution) equal to 2.5?

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables the PDF of $Z=X+Y$ is given by

$f_{z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{x}(z-y)\, f_{y}(y)\, dy,$

here is a [link with examples](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) .

This operation is known as a convolution. You can calculate the integral directly or you can use Laplace Transforms or Fourier Transforms. I think these transforms are referred to as Moment Generating Functions in the Statistics literature.

Comment: Not quite (in relation to your last sentence) -- Laplace transforms are (apart from a sign in the exponent) MGFs but Fourier transforms (again, aside from a sign in the exponent) *characteristic functions*.